# RDKit compilation fails due missing Freetype font

Tags: freetype, rdkit

I'm trying to build RDKit version 2021_03_5 from source on Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm getting the error below. I don't see anything about this in the [official documentation](http://rdkit.org/docs/Install.html#building-from-source). Does anyone know what I need to install to get past this error?

```
Downloading https://fonts.google.com/download?family=Comic%20Neue...
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find Freetype (missing: FREETYPE_LIBRARY FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindFreetype.cmake:157 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  Code/GraphMol/MolDraw2D/CMakeLists.txt:81 (find_package)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that simply installing 'libfreetype6-dev' got me past the error.

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
```

Even though this worked, I still feel like I've done something wrong since it's not listed as a prerequisite in the installation instructions.